# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value for image

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I am trying to add 2 textfields and 1 image to a table view but I have trouble retrieving the image, here are my codes

this is for the adding of a cell, I got the optional error on the 'slot image: data["slot image"] as! String line'

```
static func loadShift(onComplete:@escaping (([Shift]) -> Void)){
        db.collection("shifts").getDocuments() {(querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            onComplete([])
        } else {
            var shiftslists: [Shift] = []
            for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                let data = document.data()
                let shift = Shift(
                    id: document.documentID,
                    day: data["day"] as! String,
                    slot: data["slot"] as! String,
                    slotimage: data["slotimage"] as! String)
                shiftslists.append(shift)
            }
            onComplete(shiftslists)
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the code I tried to retrieve the image from which is in another view controller/file, what I am trying to do is that when the user chooses a slot from a picker view be it am, pm, or full day, it will show a different image

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let shiftItem = shift {
            let isNew = shiftItem.id == ""
            title = isNew ? "Add Shift" : "Edit Shift"
            dateTextField.text = shiftItem.day
            timeTextField.text = shiftItem.slot

            // slot image

            if timeTextField.text == "AM Slot"{
                shiftItem.slotimage = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/dc/15/94/dc1594d8490ec06d862ea97e770140cf.jpg"
            }
            if timeTextField.text == "PM Slot" {
                shiftItem.slotimage = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3d/e2/00/3de200e185ceaf3b313c4dc93c8f115a.jpg"
            } else {
                shiftItem.slotimage = "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e1/4c/14/e14c1452e89b760916a2967a75ad8bfa.jpg"
            }          
        }
    }
```

and the choice they chose from a picker view is shown in a text field hence why I used the timeTextField.text

where did I go wrong such that the image could not get retrieved and became nil?

All help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's two things here I think you need to check: `Optional` value and `Async` method.
I believe you haven't update your Firebase's `shifts` collection properly and trying to force unwrapped value: `data["slotimage"]`.
Try these steps:

- safe uwrap your optional: like `data["slotimage"] ?? ""`, or `if let image = data["slotimage"] { }`
- check and update your Firebase documents directly to make sure `shiftItem.slotimage` is presented.

Comment: hi! so I have checked my firebase db and slot image wasn't created so I added it and now I have the same error at the line I Asterix `// Image
       ** let url = URL(string: s.slotimage)!**
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            // Fetch Image Data
            if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // Create Image and Update Image View
                    cell.slotImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }` this is in my tableview file at func tableview

Comment: I realised that in my firebase, the data didn't get retrieved but the field did, so what was recorded was day: "", slot "", and I added slotimage: "" manually

Comment: I don't think im supposed to add the slot image field in firebase manually so Im back to square 1 :/